# Error al actualizar registros de tipo Varchar a INT mediante formulario con comboBox

Tags: c#, sql-server-2008-r2

Tengo un problema al actualizar los campos de mi tabla. Dentro del formulario cuento con un `comboBox` donde muestro los campos de mi tabla de tipo `Varchar` pero al seleccionar uno de ellos me guarde el id de ese departamento. Mi problema se genera al actualizar mostrando el siguiente error:

> "ErroSystem.SqlClient.SqlException(0x80131904): Conversion failed when converting the varchar value 'Compras' to data type int".

Para modificar mi registro, primero realizó la busqueda mediante un botón BUSCAR donde lee el número de control de la persona. Con el siguiente método.

```
public void buscarNumeroControl()
    {
        // string cod = textBox1.Text;
        try
        {
            string cadena = "SELECT nombre, apellidoP, depto FROM Personal INNER JOIN  Departamento ON Personal.id_Depto=Departamento.id_Depto WHERE id_numControl='" + textBox1.Text + "' ";
            SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(cadena, con);
            con.Open();
            SqlDataReader registro = cmd.ExecuteReader();
            if (registro.Read() == true)
            {
                textBox2.Text = registro["nombre"].ToString();
                textBox3.Text = registro["apellidoP"].ToString();
                comboDepto.Text = registro["depto"].ToString();
                actualizar.Enabled = true;
            }
            else
            {
                MessageBox.Show("No existe un artículo con el código ingresado");

            }
            con.Close();
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            MessageBox.Show("Error" + ex.ToString());
        }

    }
```

El comboBox lo lleno de la siguiente manera.

```
public void llenarcomboboxDepto()
    {
        try{
        con.Open();
        DataSet dsd = new DataSet();

        SqlDataAdapter cmd = new SqlDataAdapter("SELECT id_Depto, depto FROM Departamento", con);
        //se indica con que tabla se llena

        cmd.Fill(dsd, "Departamento");

        comboDepto.DataSource = dsd.Tables[0].DefaultView;

        //indicamos el valor de los miembros

        comboDepto.ValueMember = "id_Depto";

        //se indica el valor a desplegar en el combobox

        comboDepto.DisplayMember = "depto";
        con.Close();
         }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            MessageBox.Show("Error" + ex.ToString());
        } 
    }
```

y para modificar tengo el botón ACTUALIZAR invocando el siguiente método.

```
public void modificarRegistro()
    {
        try
        {
            con.Open();
            string cadena = "UPDATE Personal set nombre='" + textBox2.Text + "', apellidoP='" + textBox3.Text + "' , id_Depto='" + comboDepto.Text + "'  WHERE id_numControl='" + textBox1.Text + "'";
            SqlCommand comando = new SqlCommand(cadena, con);
            int cant;
            cant = comando.ExecuteNonQuery();
            if (cant == 1)
            {
                MessageBox.Show("Se modificaron los datos correctamente");
                textBox1.Text = "";
                textBox2.Text = "";
                textBox3.Text = "";
                comboDepto.Text = "";
                con.Close();
            }
            else
            {
                MessageBox.Show("No existe la persona con ese numero de control");

                actualizar.Enabled = false;
            }
            // }

        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            MessageBox.Show("Error" + ex.ToString());
        }
    }
```

No se en que parte este mal, siento que no me esta recuperando el id del departamento que estoy seleccionado. Alguien podria ayudarme porfavor.

Comment: Para obtener el `id_Depto` debe usar la propiedad `SelectedValue` del `ComboBox` de esta manera: `comboDepto.SelectedValue`

Comment: Fuera del tema te recomiendo que realices el [tour] para que veas como funciona el sitio y ademas ganar tu primera medalla.

Comment: Y usar ado.net es ya algo bastante desfasado, cambia a algo mas moderno, mínimo dapper.

Comment: Se debe usar **siempre** querys parametrizados, que evitan la inyección de sql.De esa manera además evitas errores de tipado.

Answer (score 0):

El id_Depto es entero y estas almacenando una cadena recupera la propiedad  SelectedValue y no el Text.

```
string cadena = "UPDATE Personal set nombre='" + textBox2.Text + "', apellidoP='" + textBox3.Text + "' , id_Depto='" + comboDepto.SelectedValue + "'  WHERE id_numControl='" + textBox1.Text + "'";
```

Comment: Esto es incorrecto: `id_Depto='" + comboDepto.ValueMember`

Answer (score 0):

Creo que la sentencia correcta debe ser:

```
string cadena = "UPDATE Personal set nombre='" + textBox2.Text + "', apellidoP='" + textBox3.Text + "' , id_Depto=" + comboDepto.SelectedValue.ToString() + " WHERE id_numControl=" + textBox1.Text;
```

Se debe tener especial cuidado con las comillas simples.

**EDIT**: Quedaría de esta forma utilizando parámetros...

```
public void modificarRegistro()
{
    int cant=0;
    string cadena = "UPDATE Personal SET nombre=@nombre, apellidoP=@apellido , id_Depto=@iddepto WHERE id_numControl=@id";

    using (var comando = new SqlCommand(cadena, con))
    {
        //Recomendado para tipos de datos especializados como latitud, longitud, decimales, money, etc.
        command.Parameters.Add("@nombre", SqlDbType.NVarChar); //Debe ser el mismo tipo de datos definido en tu SQL SERVER
        command.Parameters["@nombre"].Value = textBox2.Text;

        //Genial para tipos de datos comunes
        command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@apellido", textBox3.Text);
        command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@iddepto", comboDepto.SelectedValue);
        command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@id", textBox1.Text);

        try
        {
            con.Open();
            cant = comando.ExecuteNonQuery();
            if (cant == 1)
            {
                textBox1.Text = string.Empty;
                textBox2.Text = string.Empty;
                textBox3.Text = string.Empty;
                comboDepto.SelectedIndex = -1; //O puedes colocar 0 (cero)
                MessageBox.Show("Se modificaron los datos correctamente");
            }
            else
            {
                actualizar.Enabled = false;

                MessageBox.Show("No existe la persona con ese numero de control");
            }
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            MessageBox.Show("Error" + ex.ToString());
        }
        finally
        {
            //Se cierra la conexión haya o no error.
            con.Close();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Es posible que tu respuesta sea correcta, pero hay que enseñar sobre todo a los nuevos que nunca se deben crear queries concatenando cadenas. Se debe usar **siempre** querys parametrizados, que evitan la inyección de sql.

Comment: Podrian darme un ejemplo de como aplicar a mi codigo el querys parametrizados porfavor.

Comment: @Daniel respuesta editada :)

Comment: Muchas gracias Christian, cada dia aprendo mas. Te lo agradezco :)